# Button only prints one number

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, calculator

I have a number pad for a calculator, when I push the button only one number appears on the `JTextField`, even thought I pressed the button twice. How do I allow the user to press a button more than once to make the numbers appear more than once on the `JTextField`. For example, if someone pressed the one key twice, 11 would appear. Here is my code for this portion and any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("1")){
        numField.setText("1");
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `numField.setText(numField.getText()+"1");`

Comment: KeyBindings (search more ---> Java swing calculator)

Comment: Hmm, no, I would not use key bindings for this.  Action command like the OP has is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the old text and append the new one on it like this

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("1")){
        numField.setText(numField.getText() + "1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just thought of that right as you posted. Makes sense because its getting the text and adding the hard coded one at the end.

Comment: @Blastoize34 You might aswell mark the helpful answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

.setText is going to set whatever your thing is inside of that.

Suggestion:
Have a global variable and add to it and setText to that global variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in your code, is setting the text "1"...
Look at this line to change it, how can you think of a way to make it so that you add to the end of the string that is already in the textField?

```
numField.setText("1");
```

Answer (score 0):

"set" sets the field text.  It doesn't add to the field text.  Given the code above, it doesn't matter if you press the button twice or thirty times, the result will always be a single "1" in the field.

SAVE THE RESULT in a different variable, then display that variable.

```
StringBuilder accumulator = new StringBuilder();

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    accumulator.append( e.getActionCommand() );
    numField.setText( accumulator.toString() );
}
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Another strategy to do this:

```
   final Set<String> actionSet = new HashSet<String>();
   actionSet.add("1");
   actionSet.add("2");
   actionSet.add("3");

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if(actionSet.contains(e.getActionCommand())){
           numField.setText(numField.getText() + e.getActionCommand());
       }
   }
```